# jQuery/bootstrap - div is displayed in unexpected place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a problem with displaying divs after click on the image, structure of page is like this:

```
 IMAGE1    IMAGE2   IMAGE3
```

When I click on second image, then particular div should be displayed below second image, but it looks like that:

After click image2:

```
IMAGE1    IMAGE2    IMAGE3
CONTENT2
```

Content2 should be under Image2

All divs with contents display well only if I click images in sequence 1-2-3, and I think that it's because bootstrap's class `col-md`, which has set float to the left. How can I solve this problem? In order to after click Image3,  Content3 will be display under Image3

JavaScript:

```
var images = $(".flower-image");


images.on("click", function() {

var index = images.index(this);


$(".content-flowers").eq(index).toggle(1000);
});
```

HTML:

```
div class="row">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">

                    <div style="display: none;" class="content-flowers">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                                <p> CONTENT </p>                                                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: block;" class="content-flowers">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                                <p> CONTENT </p>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: block;" class="content-flowers">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                                <p> CONTENT </p>        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `<p>` tags containing "CONTENT" are of a specified size you could create an empty element that works as a placeholder. When you toggle a CONTENT `<p>` element you could also toggle the empty placeholder element respectively.

Comment: I put <p> as a example, in my file I have <div class="jumbotron"> which is bootstrap's class

Comment: You could do the same thing with empty placeholder `<div class="jumbotron">`, however @Kld's suggestion seems like it might require less of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = $(".flower-image");


images.on("click", function() {    
      var index = images.index(this); 
      $(".content-flowers").eq(index).toggle(1000).addClass('md-col-offset-' + index * 4);
});
```

Or using the css class **col-md-offset-4** attribute in the html

```
div class="row">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">

                    <div style="display: none;" class="content-flowers">
                        <div class="col-md-4 ">
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                                <p> CONTENT </p>                                                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: block;" class="content-flowers">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                                <p> CONTENT </p>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: block;" class="content-flowers">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                                <p> CONTENT </p>        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scaffolding and positioning of elements matters. It starts with a row and then columns. I created a fiddle here that should be doing close to what you are asking.

https://jsfiddle.net/mw9g0eLk/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <img class="img1 flower-image" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif" style="width:50px;" />
      <div style="display: none;" class="content-flowers">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <p> CONTENT IMG1 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <img class="img2 flower-image" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif" style="width:50px;" />
      <div style="display: none;" class="content-flowers">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <p> CONTENT IMG2 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <img class="img3 flower-image" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif" style="width:50px;" />
      <div style="display: none;" class="content-flowers">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <p> CONTENT IMG3 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var images = $(".flower-image");

images.on("click", function() {
  var index = images.index(this);
  $(".content-flowers").eq(index).toggle(1000);
});
```